# Prevent Ubuntu from choosing WiFi over Ethernet

Tags: 18.04, internet

My machine tends to switch arbitrarily to WiFi when my laptop is connected to Ethernet. I'm wondering how I can prevent this.

Comment: You mean, other than toggling off wifi altogether? (through a hardware switch if you have one, or through the `rfkill` command if you don't)

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue? You can have both wifi and ethernet active. Do you see your speed changing when this happens? Could it just be that the icon changes but you're still connected via both network cards?

Comment: Seems odd to me; wired always is preferred. You can set priorities on connections in network manager. It might be your wireless has a higher priority set?! If so that might explain it.

Comment: A dodgy ethernet cable would also explain it.

Comment: I can confirm that my ethernet disappears since I lose access to data only accessible through a wired connection(or vpn). Hence the irritation of always having to reconnect.